# Can Cytoscape.js with Dagre layout draw a vertical tree?

Tags: cytoscape.js

Is it possible to configure this to display a vertical tree instead of a horizontal tree? What I mean by vertical is something similar to Windows Explorer.

We have some users that would prefer to work with it that way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [js.cytoscape generating graph left to right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51947430/js-cytoscape-generating-graph-left-to-right)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dagre layout extension has a [github page](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-dagre) with some useful default values for the layout:

```
var defaults = {
    nodeSep: undefined, // the separation between adjacent nodes in the same rank
    edgeSep: undefined, // the separation between adjacent edges in the same rank
    rankSep: undefined, // the separation between adjacent nodes in the same rank
    rankDir: undefined // 'TB' for top to bottom flow, 'LR' for left to right,
    ranker: undefined, // Type of algorithm to assign a rank to each node in the input graph. Possible values: 'network-simplex', 'tight-tree' or 'longest-path'
    minLen: function( edge ){ return 1; }, // number of ranks to keep between the source and target of the edge
    edgeWeight: function( edge ){ return 1; }, // higher weight edges are generally made shorter and straighter than lower weight edges

    // general layout options
    fit: true, // whether to fit to viewport
    padding: 30, // fit padding
    spacingFactor: undefined, // Applies a multiplicative factor (>0) to expand or compress the overall area that the nodes take up
    nodeDimensionsIncludeLabels: false, // whether labels should be included in determining the space used by a node
    animate: false, // whether to transition the node positions
    animateFilter: function( node, i ){ return true; }, // whether to animate specific nodes when animation is on; non-animated nodes immediately go to their final positions
    animationDuration: 500, // duration of animation in ms if enabled
    animationEasing: undefined, // easing of animation if enabled
    boundingBox: undefined, // constrain layout bounds; { x1, y1, x2, y2 } or { x1, y1, w, h }
    transform: function( node, pos ){ return pos; }, // a function that applies a transform to the final node position
    ready: function(){}, // on layoutready
    stop: function(){} // on layoutstop
}
```

The important part here is the rankDir, you can define LR there :)